# How to calculate generalized discrete convolution without using DiscreteConvolve

Tags: summation, convolution

I want to find the discrete convolution of two functions which potentially do not share a common domain. For example I have

```
a[y_, a0_, a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_] :=Piecewise[{{1-a0,y==-2.4},{a0-a1,y==-1.5},{a1-a2,y==2.6},{a2,y==3.1},{a3,y==4.5},{a4,y==5.7}},0]


aa[y_, a0_, a1_, a2_] := Piecewise[{{1 - a0, y == -1.75}, {a0 - a1, y == 1.55}, {a1 - a2,  y == 2.25}, {a2, y == 3.75}}, 0]


DiscreteConvolve[a[y, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4], aa[y, a0, a1, a2], y, x]
```

or

```
DiscreteConvolve[a[y, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4], a[y, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4], y, x]
```

Here interesting point is the total non-zero points of the result of the convolution. Unfortunately here `DiscreteConvolve` doesnt work.

The formula used to calculate the discrete convolution of two discrete functions can be given as follows:

\begin{equation}
c(z)=\sum_{i_1=1}^M\sum_{i_2=1}^N a(y_1^{i_1})b(y_2^{i_2})\delta\left(\sum_{k=1}^2y_k^{i_k}-z\right)
\end{equation}

Here $M$ is the total number of non-zero elements of the function $a$, $N$ is the total number of non-zero elements of function $b$ and $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta function which is $\delta(0)=1$ and $\delta(x \neq 0)=0$.

Also $y_1^{i_1}$ is the index set (domain of the function $a$), e.g., above we have $y_1^{1}=-2.4$, $y_1^{2}=-1.5$, $y_1^{3}=2.6$, $y_1^{4}=3.1$, $y_1^{5}=4.5$, $y_1^{6}=5.7$ for the domain of the function $a$.

Similarly $y_2^{i_2}$ is the index set of the function $b$. Above if we consider $aa$ function then we have $y_2^{1}=-1.75$, $y_2^{2}=2.25$, $y_2^{3}=3.75$,

Can we calculate such general version of the convolution without using the `DiscreteConvolve` function?

Comment: ListConvolve is pretty general and has lots of options.

Comment: @bills I dont see any domain information extracted after ListConvolve. I have the feelinf that it is for Lists which are indexed from 0 to N.

Comment: Probably the lists are indexed 1 to N, but surely you can figure out the meaning of "1" and "N" in your problem.

Comment: @bills Can you give an example? Like above a convolved by a? What’s is the result?

Comment: Using your  defs of a[] and aa[] try... lista = a[#, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4] & /@ Range[-10, 10, 0.05]; listaa = aa[#, a0, a1, a2] & /@ Range[-10, 10, 0.05]; ListConvolve[listaa, lista, {1, -1}]. I discretized them at a sampling rate of 0.05 since that seemed to be the common time base.

Comment: @bills No. It has a weird output with many zeros and nonzeros. There is a special way of doing it as given in the formula. Convolving aa with itself should give me 21 discrete values on some discrete domain. So I must have 21 domain values and 21 values as the result of convolution.

Comment: Your functions a and aa are mostly zero (except at specific values of y). Hence each of the sequences, sampled regularly, have many zeros and so the convolutions have many zeros. For your example, if you let q = ListConvolve[listaa, listaa, {1, -1}], then Select[q, # =!= 0 &], you will find 20 nonzero entries (almost as you expect).

Comment: @bills as I said the results of ListConvolve are totally wrong. The total number of non-zero values for colvolving aa with aa is n(n+1)/2 so it must be 10 for aa and 21 for a.